# AdMob integration destorts the Hello World Label text

Tags: objective-c, admob, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have created a simple hello world project for cocos2d-x 3.2. Added AdMob banner. The essence of adding banner is to create a view, then add into that view first the cocos2d-x content and then banner content:

```
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self addChildViewController:_contentController];
[contentView addSubview:_contentController.view];
[_contentController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[contentView addSubview:_bannerView];
self.view = contentView;
```

The result is that on iPhone, iPhone Retina, iPad Retina (but not in iPad) the Hello World text is distorted like this:

[image]

At the same time that stats text is not distorted:

[image]

I cannot understand what happens and why. Here is my full code:

`.h`file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BannerViewController : UIViewController

- (instancetype)initWithContentViewController:(UIViewController *)contentController;
- (void) hideBanner;
- (void) showBanner;

@end
```

and hers is `.mm` file

```
#import "BannerViewController.h"
#import "GADBannerView.h"

@interface BannerViewController () <GADBannerViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation BannerViewController {
    GADBannerView *_bannerView;
    UIViewController *_contentController;
    Boolean _bannerLoaded;
}

- (instancetype)initWithContentViewController:(UIViewController *)contentController
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        // use kGADAdSizeBanner for a small banner in iPad
        _bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait]; // scaled banner dependent on device size
        _bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-874958723945898/8247587858";
        _bannerView.delegate = self;
        _contentController = contentController;
        _bannerLoaded = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView
{
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self addChildViewController:_contentController];
    [contentView addSubview:_contentController.view];
    [_contentController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [contentView addSubview:_bannerView];
    self.view = contentView;
}

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_6_0
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return [_contentController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}
#endif

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [_contentController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [_contentController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

// For animation
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;
    CGRect bannerFrame = CGRectZero;
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_6_0
    bannerFrame = _bannerView.frame;
#else
    bannerFrame.size = [_bannerView sizeThatFits:contentFrame.size];
#endif

    bannerFrame.origin.x = (contentFrame.size.width - bannerFrame.size.width) / 2;

    if (_bannerLoaded) {
        //contentFrame.size.height -= bannerFrame.size.height;
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height - bannerFrame.size.height;
    } else {
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    }

    _contentController.view.frame = contentFrame;
    _bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _bannerView.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_bannerView];

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    [_bannerView loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)bannerView
{
    NSLog(@"adViewDidReceiveAd");
    _bannerLoaded = YES;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"adView didFailToReceiveAdWithError");
    _bannerLoaded = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

- (void) hideBanner{
    //TODO:
}

- (void) showBanner{
    //TODO:
}

- (void)dealloc {
    _bannerView.delegate = nil;
    [_bannerView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
// </GADBannerViewDelegate>
```

And I use it in `AppController.mm` like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Init the CCEAGLView
    CCEAGLView *eaglView = [CCEAGLView viewWithFrame: [window bounds]
                                     pixelFormat: kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                     depthFormat: GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES
                              preserveBackbuffer: NO
                                      sharegroup: nil
                                   multiSampling: NO
                                 numberOfSamples: 0];

    // Use RootViewController manage CCEAGLView 
    _viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    _viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    _viewController.view = eaglView;

    _bannerViewController = [[BannerViewController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_viewController];

    // Set RootViewController to window
    if ( [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] < 6.0)
    {
        // warning: addSubView doesn't work on iOS6
        [window addSubview: _bannerViewController.view];
        //[window addSubview: _viewController.view];
    }
    else
    {
        // use this method on ios6
        [window setRootViewController:_bannerViewController];
        // [window setRootViewController:_viewController];
    }

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:true];

    // IMPORTANT: Setting the GLView should be done after creating the RootViewController
    cocos2d::GLView *glview = cocos2d::GLView::createWithEAGLView(eaglView);
    cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->setOpenGLView(glview);

    cocos2d::Application::getInstance()->run();

    return YES;
}
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. I appears that there is a time in hours written with black color like in the image, which on on the Hello World label and hence it distorts:

[image]

The time is shown is simulators status bar. In order to hide it I added this:

```
//fix not hide status on ios7
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

into BannerViewController class and that's it!